# How to get single image from Live Photo in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uiimageview, ios9

As we know apple has introduce new image called "Live Photo". Live photo looks like very shore video. Here my question is how can we get each frame or images form Live photo so that we can make other opration on this images like editing,sharing etc.

Answer (score 2):

PHLivePhoto has a UIImage *image property
edit: and an AVAsset * videoAsset for the video

Comment: But they are both private.

Comment: It doesn't have any image properties

Answer (score 0):

If you pick the live photo using UIImagePicker, you can get one single image like this：

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```